# Desktop version of web app can access REST API, iOS version can't

Tags: ios, cordova, rest, meteor, jsonp

I'm building a Meteor app using Cordova, and I'm accessing a WordPress REST API via JSONP. It works totally fine on the desktop version of the web app, but in the iOS Simulator and on my device, I get an error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

I don't understand why suddenly the service wants authorization of some kind. On the desktop I can point a totally fresh browser session to the URL in question without being logged into anything, and it works just fine.

Am I missing something simple?

EDIT:

AJAX call below:

```
  const apiBaseUrl = '<censored>';

  function getRecentPosts(callback) {
    $.ajax(`${apiBaseUrl}/get_recent_posts`, {
      dataType: 'jsonp'
    }).done(function (data) {
      console.log('done, firing callback');
      callback(data.posts);
    });
  }
```

And I did check, `jQuery.ajax` does exist on the device (I thought maybe jQuery which is packaged with my app wasn't working).

Comment: If you can open a fresh browser on Desktop, then I'd suspect it's something to do with the implementation you're using to access the API on your mobile app. Maybe you're directing it to an incorrect endpoint? I'd suggest posting your networking code. :)

Answer (score 0):

This was a very niche problem that's related to Meteor. The solution was to add this line:

```
App.accessRule("*");
```

to `/mobile-config.js`.

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/App-accessRule